# Issues when resize frame for mobile and desktop

Tags: javascript, mobile, iframe, resize, three.js

I want my frame to auto resize height to ... when screen width is smaller than ... (like sketchfab here, i recorded : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_y5ckVFGHKU&feature=youtu.be )

This is how far i can go :

```
var container, stats, loader;
var camera, cameraControls, scene, renderer;
init();
animate();


function init() {

container = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(container);

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 700 / 450, 1, 10000);
camera.position.z = 1500;
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false, alpha: false } );
renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000 );
renderer.setSize( 700, 450 );

controls = new THREE.OrbitAndPanControls( camera, renderer.domElement );


// scene

scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add( camera );
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x273e10 );
            scene.add( ambientLight );
var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1.2, 100000 );
            pointLight.position.set( -100, 400, 200 );

            camera.add( pointLight );

            var ambient = 0xffffff, diffuse = 0xffffff, specular = 0x585858, shininess = 100;

            var shader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "normalmap" ];
            var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( shader.uniforms );

            uniforms[ "tNormal" ].value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "obj/leeperrysmith/512 NORMAL_normals.jpg" );
            uniforms[ "uNormalScale" ].value.set( 1, 1 );

            uniforms[ "tDiffuse" ].value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "obj/leeperrysmith/datma1k4 copy.jpg" );

            uniforms[ "enableDiffuse" ].value = true;

            uniforms[ "uDiffuseColor" ].value.setHex( diffuse );
            uniforms[ "uSpecularColor" ].value.setHex( specular );
            uniforms[ "uAmbientColor" ].value.setHex( ambient );

            uniforms[ "uShininess" ].value = shininess;


            var parameters = { fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader, vertexShader: shader.vertexShader, uniforms: uniforms, lights: true };
            var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( parameters );


            loader = new THREE.JSONLoader( true );
            loader.load( "obj/leeperrysmith/datmascale.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, 100, material ) } );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);}
 function createScene( geometry, scale, material ) {

            geometry.computeTangents();
            geometry.computeVertexNormals();
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            mesh.position.y = - 0;
            mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = scale;
            scene.add( mesh );
          }

function onWindowResize() {

if (  window.innerWidth < 650 ) {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / 350;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, 350);

    if ( window.innerWidth < 500 ) {
           camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / 250;
           camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
           renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, 250);
    }
}
else {
    camera.aspect = 700 / 450;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(700, 450);
    }}
function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
controls.update();
render();
}

function render() {

renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

I embed it to my webpage by iframe:

```
<iframe src="/full/1.html" width="80%" height="450" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

And the problems is when the frame height resize smaller, it leave a space.

Screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEOz2.jpg

How to resize frame height smaller when width to limit but do not leave the space like sketchfab did?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the fact you are fixing your iFrame height to 450px when you create it in the html :

```
<iframe src="/full/1.html" width="80%" height="450"....
```

And in your onResize function, you are updating the viewport height but not your frame height.

Adding an id to your frame like this :

```
<iframe id="myFrame" src="/full/1.html" width="80%" height="450"....
```

And updating the height of your frame in the onResize function with a call like :

```
document.getElementById("myFrame").style.height = 200px; ...
```

might solve your issue.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for answer,i did extractly like you said and i got this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null    Can you fix this error?

Comment: @n2g6t1q1 My first guess is that your html code is loaded after the call of your javascript and then the id "myFrame" is not recognised at the first call. You can move your js to the end of your html or use an"onLoad" function to be sure the js is called once the page is fully loaded. Hope this help

Comment: Aww, i don't know how to add onLoad function to my code, can you edit it to my code?

Comment: @n2g6t1q1 : It was just a guess. Have you tried to move your code to the end of your html? It is the easiest way to solve your error I guess. Tell me if it works , if not, post your whole code.

Comment: I think there is a confusion here. In fact you have 2 html pages. therefore you have to code 2 onResize functions. The first on the page containing your iframe which will resize the frame. The second one on the embbed page resizing the viewport on resize. If it ain't clear enough , tell me and i'll post another answer.

Comment: Are there anyway to resize all viewport and iframe in just one html? i don't like add scripts to web html.

Comment: It depends, can u get rid of the iframe or is it necessary for your project? If you can't do the job without iframe and if you want to keep that kinda dynamics, I guess it's not possible on an easy way, but seriously, it ain't that difficult to code a bit of js to adjust your iframe on resize event. Just saying.